# how to align four figures (3 figures with a caption and 1 figure with another caption) next to each other in a single row in ieee format in latex

Tags: floats

How I can add 4 figures, three figures within a caption and fourth figure with another caption in a single row in overleaf?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There is more than one "ieee format". Are you maybe referring to the `IEEEtran` document class? If so, with which options do you execute `\documentclass{...}{IEEEtran}`? If not, do please provide more information about your document setup.

Comment: You probably want a figure* for the whole thing, and one minipage per caption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `IEEEtran` document class, the following solution may be of interest to you. It employs two side-by-side `minipage` environments inside a `figure*` environment. The first `minipage` contains three `\includegraphics` directives and one `\caption` command; the second `minipage` environment contains one `\includegraphics` directive and one `\caption` command.

[image]

Do note that LaTeX is programmed to place `figure*` environments (and `table*` environments too, for that matter) at the top of a page.

```
\documentclass[demo]{IEEEtran} % omit 'demo' version in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{figYa}
\hspace{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{figYb}
\hspace{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{figYc}

\caption{A figure with three graphs}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figZ}

\caption{A figure with a single graph}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You... I am using IEEEtran document class.. Your answer solves my problem...